# Python/Django, decryption works in shell but not during test

Tags: python, django, shell, encryption

The project I'm working on uses [Fernet](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/) for encryption, we need to store access tokens. For some reason decryption works fine when running code in the shell but the test fails because the access token doesn't get decrypted.

**First question**

Is there a difference between running code in the Django shell and running code via tests? This could explain my troubles.

**Second question**

If there is no difference between running code in the Django shell and during a test the problem comes from elsewhere. Please read on and check the code below to make things more clear.

Both in the shell and the test I load the same object from the database, lets call this object facebookToken. When I run facebookToken.decryptedAccessToken it works just fine. However, the same code doesn't working while running the test, decryptedAccessToken returns the encrypted value!

*The class that handles encryption*

```
class Gatekeeper(object):
"""A simple class to encrypt en decrypt strings."""

key = settings.FERNET_KEY

def encrypt(self, secret):
    """Return an encrypted string.

    attribute secret: a string to encrypt
    """
    fernet = Fernet(self.key)
    # cast string to bytes
    secret = secret.encode()
    encryptedSecret = fernet.encrypt(secret)
    return encryptedSecret

def decrypt(self, secret):
    """Return a decrypted string.

    attribute secret: a secret string to decrypt
    """

    print '\n \n secret', secret
    fernet = Fernet(self.key)
    # cast string to bytes
    secret = secret.encode()
    print '\n \n ENCODED secret', secret
    decryptedSecret = fernet.decrypt(secret)
    print '\n \n decryptedSecret', decryptedSecret
    return decryptedSecret
```

*Custom encrypted text field class.*

```
class EncryptedTextField(models.TextField):
"""A custom textfield for storing sensitive information."""

description = "A textfield for storing sensitive information."

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EncryptedTextField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
    """Return encrypted value or None.

    This method encryps the value before storing it in the database.
    """
    if value is not None:
        value = Gatekeeper().encrypt(value)

    return value
```

*Abstract AccessToken class*

```
class AccessToken(models.Model):
"""Abstract class for Access tokens.

Depends on Gatekeerp, EncryptedTextField, and User class in core app!
"""
owner = models.ForeignKey('core.User')
socialMediaChannel = models.IntegerField(
    choices=socialMediaChannelList, null=False, blank=False
)
accessToken = EncryptedTextField(null=False, blank=False)
accessTokenSecret = EncryptedTextField(null=True, blank=True)
lastUpdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    abstract = True

@classmethod
def getAccessTokens(cls, user, socialMediaChannel):
    """Return a list with AccessToken objects. Filter on user and
    socialMediaChannel.

    attribute user: a user object
    attribute socialMediaChannel: a socialMediaChannel
    """

    accessTokens = cls.objects.filter(
        owner=user,
        socialMediaChannel=socialMediaChannel
    )

    return accessTokens

@property
def decryptedAccessToken(self):
    """Return decrypted accessToken."""
    return Gatekeeper().decrypt(self.accessToken)

@property
def decryptedAccessTokenSecret(self):
    """Return decrypted accessTokenSecret."""
    return Gatekeeper().decrypt(self.accessTokenSecret)
```